# How can I prove the following list is a list of all the injective maps $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ rigorously? (Munkres "Topology 2nd Edition")

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, foundations

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

The following exercise is in this book:

> Exercise 1(a) on p.44 in section 6:
> Make a list of all the injective maps $$f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}.$$
> Show that none is bijective. (This constitutes a *direct* proof that a set $A$ of cardinality three does not have cardinality four.)

I made a list of all the injective maps $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}.$
I firmly believe that the following list is correct.
But how can I prove the following list is a list of all the injective maps $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ rigorously?

$f_{1}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{1}(1)=1, f_{1}(2)=2, f_{1}(3)=3.$
$f_{2}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{2}(1)=1, f_{2}(2)=2, f_{2}(3)=4.$
$f_{3}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{3}(1)=1, f_{3}(2)=3, f_{3}(3)=2.$
$f_{4}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{4}(1)=1, f_{4}(2)=3, f_{4}(3)=4.$
$f_{5}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{5}(1)=1, f_{5}(2)=4, f_{5}(3)=2.$
$f_{6}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{6}(1)=1, f_{6}(2)=4, f_{6}(3)=3.$
$f_{7}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{7}(1)=2, f_{7}(2)=1, f_{7}(3)=3.$
$f_{8}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{8}(1)=2, f_{8}(2)=1, f_{8}(3)=4.$
$f_{9}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{9}(1)=2, f_{9}(2)=3, f_{9}(3)=1.$
$f_{10}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{10}(1)=2, f_{10}(2)=3, f_{10}(3)=4.$
$f_{11}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{11}(1)=2, f_{11}(2)=4, f_{11}(3)=1.$
$f_{12}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{12}(1)=2, f_{12}(2)=4, f_{12}(3)=3.$
$f_{13}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{13}(1)=3, f_{13}(2)=1, f_{13}(3)=2.$
$f_{14}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{14}(1)=3, f_{14}(2)=1, f_{14}(3)=4.$
$f_{15}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{15}(1)=3, f_{15}(2)=2, f_{15}(3)=1.$
$f_{16}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{16}(1)=3, f_{16}(2)=2, f_{16}(3)=4.$
$f_{17}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{17}(1)=3, f_{17}(2)=4, f_{17}(3)=1.$
$f_{18}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{18}(1)=3, f_{18}(2)=4, f_{18}(3)=2.$
$f_{19}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{19}(1)=4, f_{19}(2)=1, f_{19}(3)=2.$
$f_{20}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{20}(1)=4, f_{20}(2)=1, f_{20}(3)=3.$
$f_{21}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{21}(1)=4, f_{21}(2)=2, f_{21}(3)=1.$
$f_{22}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{22}(1)=4, f_{22}(2)=2, f_{22}(3)=3.$
$f_{23}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{23}(1)=4, f_{23}(2)=3, f_{23}(3)=1.$
$f_{24}:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f_{24}(1)=4, f_{24}(2)=3, f_{24}(3)=2.$

Comment: Hint: how many injective maps did you expect?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $4\times 3\times 2$.

Comment: I know elementary combinatorics.

Comment: Then your elementary logic is lacking :) if you found 24 distinct maps and 24 is all you expected to find in advance via an independent method, then that requirement is satisfied and you go on to claim that none of them were bijections.

Comment: As a sidenote, listing things out is not inherently unrigorous. It only feels so because we are taught this is not the way to prove an infinite number of statements. But when the number of things is finite, it is a perfectly valid and whole line of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have an injective map from $\{1,2,3\}$ into $\{1,2,3,4\}$, the image should have $3$ elements. We have four subsets of cardinality 3 and each one of those sets has $3!$ permutations.

That makes $4(3!)=24$ possible sets of images.

Thus there are $24$ injective functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ into $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, Thank you very much for your answer. But is this rigorous proof? I can understand your answer because I know elementary combinatorics.

Comment: Maybe I don't know what proof is rigorous.

Comment: It is just a counting problem.

Comment: In this book, the author proved there is no bijection from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,\dots,m\}$ if $m\neq n$. I think this is just a counting problem but the author proved this by very long argument.